# How we can update table A column by table B column value using liquibase yml script

Tags: hibernate, jpa, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I want to update table A's name column with Table B's name column value where table B's id is present in table A.
I am trying this using the liquibase yml script but its not working.

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:  
    id:  update-name  
    author:  xyz  
    changes:  
    -  update:  
        columns:  
        -  column:  
            name:  name  
            value: A.name = B.name  
        tableName: A
        where:  A.a_id = B.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to write a Liquibase script for this, here I am posting it, might be it would be helpful for someone.
I have just called the native query for updating the data from table B.name to A.name .

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:  
    id: update-name
    author: xyz  
    changes:  
      - sql:
          update A set name = b.name from B b where id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, like @raul-sharma found you can always just use "sql" to specify the exact SQL to do it. The liquibase change objects are there to hit the majority of use cases, but are not a replacement for SQL.

That being said, if you wanted to stick with the update change instead of raw sql, your original example should work with "valueComputed" instead of "value".

Like:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:  
    id:  update-name  
    author:  xyz  
    changes:  
    -  update:  
        columns:  
        -  column:  
            name:  name  
            valueComputed: A.name = B.name  
        tableName: A
        where:  A.a_id = B.id
```

Using "valueComputed" lets liquibase know it's not a string, but a function/computation and so should not be quoted.